# GPS without faker or google maps issue

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation, gps, foreground-service

I am facing the issue which I can not understand in React Native.

I am making an app which uses `react-native-geolocation-service` and `@supersami/rn-foreground-service` libraries.

I am trying to receive user location in the foreground by `Geolocation.watchPosition` with these setup:

```
{
 accuracy: {
    android: 'high',
    ios: 'best',
  },
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  distanceFilter,
  interval: 5000,
  fastestInterval: 2000,
  forceLocationManager: true,
  showLocationDialog: true,
  showsBackgroundLocationIndicator: true,
}
```

and while I am testing application in background with fake gps application (android case) everything is great, my checkpoints (the lat and lon points which I am comparing with current user location) have been collected, foreground notification is updating.

But the case is when I want to get rid of the simulation and I am going for real-life tests.
I gave the `Always use location` in settings and I'm using following persmissions:

```
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
```

And now I can not reach any checkpoint and there is no changing geolocation which I am dispalying in notification.

I'm using values from `useRef` in geolocation listener and it is ok, everything is working when there is navigation or fake gps running, so I suppose that logic for collecting and updating foreground notification is correct.

It seems to work only when something else is using localization...

Case is only for Android, I am using Android 12.

Can someone explain me what I am missing ?

Thank you guys in advance!

EDIT: I am using `getLocation` in the loop instead of `watchLocation`.

EDIT 2: After switching to watchGeolocation in

```
 useEffect(() => {
    ReactNativeForegroundService.add_task(() => {
      backgroundWatchId.current = Geolocation.watchPosition(
        async ({ coords }) => {
          console.log('[ping]');
          if (currentRegattaRef.current?.checkpointsDetails.every((e) => e.completedTime)) {
            currentRegattaRef.current = { ...currentRegattaRef.current, status: 'ready-to-upload' };
          }

          if (!currentCheckpointRef.current || !currentRegattaRef.current || currentRegattaRef.current.status === 'ready-to-upload') return;
          console.log(currentRegattaRef.current);
          const { latitude, longitude } = coords;
          const hasReached = verifyAreBoatIsWithinCheckpoint(
            {
              lat: latitude,
              lng: longitude,
            },
            currentCheckpointRef.current.waypoint,
          );

          ReactNativeForegroundService.update({
            id: 420,
            title: 'Sailing is active! ⛵️',
            message: `To checkpoints: ${getDistance(
              { latitude, longitude },
              currentCheckpointRef.current.waypoint,
              DISTANCE_ACCURACY,
            )}`,
            icon: 'ic_small_icon',
            progress: {
              max: currentRegattaRef.current.checkpointsDetails.length,
              curr: currentCheckpointRef.current.index,
            },
          });

          if (hasReached && isActiveRegattaRef.current) {
            onArriveToTheCheckpointBackground(currentRegattaRef.current, currentCheckpointRef.current);
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        },
        GEO_OPTIONS,
      );
    }, {
      delay: 1000,
      onLoop: false,
      taskId: 'taskid',
      onError: (e) => console.log('Error logging:', e),
    });
  }, []);
```

in died after ~1min fine working in background

SOLUTION: I will leave it for feature lost programmers. You have to use `watchPosition` and **disable** battery optimization in the app settings.